# Given Unique (col1, col2), then how can we update col2 that avoid the duplicated error?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Ok, I have a table MW

```
M - O - N
1 - 1 - 5
1 - 2 - 7
1 - 3 - 8
1 - 4 - 9
```

Primary key (M, N)

Unique key (M, O)

Actually column O is the order Number of N against M, so I want to reorder to make that table like this:

```
M - O - N
1 - 3 - 5
1 - 1 - 7
1 - 4 - 8
1 - 2 - 9
```

In the 1st table the orderNo of N is 1 & now I want it 3 & so on.

In Java, I can run the update 1 row at a time,

```
Update MN set O=3 where M=1 and N=5
```

However, this query will get error because M-O is unique, since the O=3 still existed, then we can not set O=3 for N=5 unless we deleted N=8.

So, how to solve this problem in Java and/or Mysql?

Comment: In mysql drop the `M-O` unique constraint and execute the `update` query.

Comment: In this case you should apply update on the ro where `O` is `3` in original (*first) output..
`Update MN set O=4 where M=1 and N=9`

Comment: but at that time O=3 is till existed

Comment: @ Aziz, then we have to set the Unique back? that costly

Answer (score -1):

Either drop the constraints and put them back later, or put the data into a temporary table and then move it back. There's no way to do this row-by-row while maintaining your constraints.